# Url marked as malicious site by Mcafree

Tags: security, web

I have recently created a website for my client, but when I try to post to my facebook or Linkedin, I noticed that the web security advisor shows it is malicious site and given it a red cross after the link.

[image]

I would like to know what is going wrong with this url? Any solution to fix it up?

Comment: How long ago did you register this domain?

Comment: This domain name has been registered for years.

Comment: Okay so it is not some kind of "this domain is to new to be trusted" issue

Comment: I'm wondering how to get it resolved. Otherwise, visitors might think it is spammy website or unsafe website and ignore it.

Comment: Even though the domain name is registered since 2017, but the client has just got me to create their website.